# Testing CEC on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, cec-client

Just installed Raspbian on a 3 B connected to a TV that supposedly supports CEC (LG 47LD450), but struggling to find any info on how to test CEC on Raspbian.

I want to confirm that it works, or alternatively isolate which part doesn't work (e.g. the cable), but the only thing that turns up in my searches is the `cec-client` command. It does nothing for me except saying that auto detect failed. Not sure what that's indicative of. I don't know if the tool is suitable for what I want.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cec-client
No device type given. Using 'recording device'
CEC Parser created - libCEC version 4.0.1
no serial port given. trying autodetect: FAILED
```

Is it supposed to fail auto detection if my cable is faulty? That I've found indications of; some threads I've found immediately start talking about cables. It just felt weird to me at first because I got the impression that `cec-client` was searching for some internal device, which doesn't require the presence of a hdmi cable. I suppose that was a wrong impression.

How do I test CEC?

### Update

I haven't found an answer yet, but...

I installed LibreELEC and could immediately conclude that 1. CEC works and that the cable is not faulty, 2. Raspbian doesn't support CEC out of the box (apparently) since it never worked in Kodi, 3. neither `cec-client` nor the suggested `tvservice` command could confirm that the software setup was insufficient — at least the way I used them.

Answer (score 2):

`tvservice -m CEC` should show supported modes.

You will only get a response if the **connected** device supports **CEC**; monitors often only respond to **DMT**.

There is no `man` page for `tvservice`, but  `tvservice -h` will show the commands.

`tvservice -d edid.dat; edidparser edid.dat` should give you all supported data.

Comment: Thank you. I got `[E] Invalid group 'CEC'`, but got a response for DMT. I guess that means the cable is faulty, assuming the TV isn't.

Comment: I'd be grateful for confirmation on my guess. Can I assume that Raspbian has all it needs and is configured for CEC to work judging by these results? Everywhere I read there's talk of compiling libcec, 4.0.1 not working, 4.0.2 working, older Raspbian working, newer not working... Not that I know what libraries `tvservice` uses.

Comment: Well, I just installed LibreELEC and can confirm there's nothing wrong with my cable. CEC works. So, technically, the question stands.

Comment: cec-client is working fine on a stock stretch install. I had to compile it under jessie, but the deb seems to be working fine. Are you certain cec is enabled on your tv? I had to enable it on my Sony.

Comment: @bobstro CEC is 100% working in LibreELEC.